# Can't stop replication sp_dropdistpublisher responds "there are subscribers defined"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running into errors:

```
exec sp_dropdistpublisher @publisher='servername'
```

response:

> *Msg 21047, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_dropdistpublisher, Line 145
>
>   Cannot drop the local distribution Publisher because there are
>   Subscribers defined.*

There is no subscriber defined, and I don't know where to find the information that makes SQL Server think that there is a subscriber defined.

I'm open to any suggestions...

Comment: If I add @ignore_distributor=1, the distribution is dropped.  But I am hoping to understand what the problem is--not just use the workaround

Comment: So this became a nonissue after discovering that it was the database installation was corrupted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using this to enumerate the list of subscribers to find if it thinks there are some defined? Notice that I'm just starting in `sp_dropdistpublisher` and reading the code to see where it checks before deleting. Just an idea.

```
--
-- Name:
-- sp_MSrepl_enumsubscriptions
--
-- Description:
--  Enumerate subscriptions on a database
--
-- Returns:
--  0 == Failed
--  1 == Succeed
--
-- Security:
--  public, db_owner check
--  Requires Certificate signature for catalog access
--
-- Notes:
--  Used by the UI to generate a list of subscriptions
--
```

Comment: I tried that, and got an empty resultset.  I will try reading the code there to see what happens, but in the meantime, I set up another set of servers and tried the same replication steps and everything seems to be working without errors.  That makes me think there's some corruption going on within the SQL software that may require a reinstall.

Comment: Oh well :\ ... that's usually the best way to define it :\